# What HTML Editor is this?

Tags: html, editor

I saw the image below in a Udemy Ad on Facebook. What HTML editor is that? I tried searching around but to no avail.

[Udemy Ad](https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDQpXjLUFy8Kdit&w=470&h=246&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fads%2Fimage%2F%3Fd%3DAQLayTA2wL9-DKnGiKwVLtXPLyW0yeiubWn-EAsQg7oy__iXoIpkj7s7i_vccOXcWASm9o7XHjrKlAfCBVld-WCecCd7YPdr9womhUnhOY7W9M-U76SZpfEJ1b3f8-QDkKa0Fq76syH5z2ei_vZhbryT&cfs=1&upscale=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the inbuilt Ruby Blue theme. There are more feature complete HTML editors out there.